# TriDef 3D support in Ubuntu with Aspire 5738DG

Tags: ubuntu, acer-aspire, 3d

I have an ACER Aspire 5738DG with Ubuntu 12.10 on it.

The graphics are ATI 4570HD. Once I tried to install drivers and I had troubles deleting the drivers because of screen errors. On my Windows 7 preinstalled version I had a TriDef 3D application to show multimedia in 3D (with glasses).

I switched to Ubuntu. Is there something I can do with my 3D hardware? I'd like to try programming graphical stuff in 3D. What skills do I need for this?

Answer (score 2):

TriDef actually *converts* traditional 2D media into 3D by figuring out the 3d geometries that may be present in a 2.5D image and translating them into some form of stereoscopic encoding (color bands, blanking, or any number of methods depending on what the hardware supports).

At this time I am not aware that any stereoscopic 3d hardware is supported at all on GNU/Linux. This technology is heavily patented, and there is very little consumer demand on the Linux platform for the functionality, so I think it will very likely be many years (if ever) until we see any driver support for this -- particularly in the open source drivers.

Also, the future is stereoscopic 3d protocol used by HDMI 1.4, which your card is too old to support.... I think if this support ever did come (e.g. with OpenGL 4.2), your best bet would be to get a Radeon HD6000 series or later, which supports HDMI 1.4, and a monitor supporting HDMI 1.4 stereoscopic 3d protocol.

Comment: really? there is no way that i can make a program to put a box on a white screen in 3d on my system?

Comment: in think that if i have the hardware and it is working , it should be possible to use some kind of 3d view,monitor oder whatsever.

Comment: No, stereoscopic 3d (most types, anyway) require very specific hardware support. 1960s-style 3d using anaglyph glasses (one lens red and one lens cyan) does not require any hardware support, just properly timed alternating images; but it will be extremely unrealistic unless your monitor is at least 120 Hz (60 Hz for each eye). As I said you need actual hardware support for the HDMI 1.4 stereoscopic protocol, requiring a newer graphics card and probably a newer monitor, **and** supporting drivers, which don't exist on Linux. So it's a long way away.

Comment: ok, and if i install windows7 back, can i make applications with 3d?

Comment: For some limited definition of "3d", probably, yes. It depends on the hardware support. If TriDef 3D was working to your satisfaction on Windows 7, then it should be possible to design an application that uses the same framework, whether it's hardware-specific or not. But, the actual technique of writing a program that uses *any* stereoscopic 3d features requires very specific programming knowledge. You might ask on stackoverflow, but before you do, perform some research on your own and learn what various APIs are available and how to use them.

Comment: Another widely used stereoscopic 3d technology is polarized 3D system. I guess Super Ubuntu has a monitor with such system because TriDef is usually distributed with such monitor.

Comment: Also, TriDef 3D doesn't only convert 2D images to 3D. It could playback 3D video and play games with polarized 3D system.

Comment: Good info @neo, but still, I am almost positive that no software exists for driving a "polarized 3D" system on Linux. Not sure why the downvote, but if someone has information about how to get some form of stereoscopic 3d working on Linux, feel free to add that info as an answer.

Comment: @neo : yes, I use glasses like we do in cinema. polarized stereoscoptic glasses. once i played mass effect 2 and it was fun.

Comment: is it possible to make some kind of "hello word" programm in 3d ? (actually i am really happy for the answers.thank you)

Comment: Playing 3D video on web-based YouTube is not difficult for PC. To make "hello world" program in 3D you would need any language that supports OpenGL.

Comment: AMD's official answer about stereoscopic 3d on Linux is that [consumer displays are not supported](http://devgurus.amd.com/thread/158704) so please stop claiming that it will work on Linux. "PC" is not "Linux". Windows is not Linux and Linux is not Windows. They are separate platforms entirely.

Comment: i will learn more about API and openGL. if anybody has good hints send me mail to.now im not sure about email posting here.just send a  PM if possible here:)

Comment: "Playing 3D video on web-based YouTube is not difficult for PC" ?? the last Tridef version i tried had no interface with the www. do you mean it is possible to stream youtube as 3d with the tridefvideoplayer?...this is a good reason to reinstall my old windows :)

Comment: and windows 7 in ubuntu/virtualbox is not working as well, right?

Comment: If you use PCI-E passthrough (IOMMU), it's *remotely possible*, but that area is still very much a matter of research and development; you'd also need two separate monitors and at least two video cards to get any use out of it. If you share the same GPU between the host and guest, then no, running Windows in a guest won't help, since you're still beholden to the graphics drivers of the Linux host.

Answer (score 0):

TriDef is not for Linux, but you can make your own 3D software. Just split the screen in two, render the Left image on the left side and the Right image on the right side. Enable Side-By-Side mode on your 3D monitor to view.